# I accidentally froze a carton of Half and Half. Is it ruined?

Tags: freezing, cream, dairy, half-and-half

My fridge got set a wee bit colder than it should've and most of my liquid stuff has frozen. Fortunately all I had in there at the moment was some bottled water, some fruit juice, and a carton of half and half.

I'm not worried about the drinks, but I know freezing can do odd things to milk and cream. Is my half and half ruined? I mainly just use it in my morning coffee, if that matters.

Answer (score 6):

I store frozen milk for emergencies all the time... Once defrosted in the fridge, I shake it for a couple of minutes and it returns to normal. It even taste the same. Australian carton and bottled milk is slightly richer than half and half; and the water to fat ratios are lower... This doesn't seem to split badly after it is frozen. As I said, defrost for 24 hours in the fridge, shake and serve.

Answer (score 1):

I froze some 10% BF cream (coffee cream) that was on sale, thinking I could stock up a bit and freeze it and that I would be saving some $, thawed it for 24 hours and  tried it in my coffee and it curdled....lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with half and half after freezing and have found that microwaving it for about 20 seconds and then stirring and using it, the problem is gone! The fat cream has just separated. The microwave seems to help it melt down enough to reincorporate back in to liquid form! 
It tastes like normal!

Answer (score 1):

I have had limited success with freezing 18% coffee creamer even when heated it still doesnt5come back together very well. Freezing 10% seems to work a bit better though but not every time either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with 18% MF coffee cream where I had bought multiple cartons and froze them. The first one I opened was so badly separated still tasted fine but was horrible texture in my coffee lol. The next one I thawed halfway on the counter and then opened the carton and poured it in a pot on medium and heat it to steaming but not boiling, let it cool down a little, put it back in the carton and in the fridge and works just perfect.

Answer (score -1):

Think about it just put it in the food processor or blender or ninja it's back to normal make sure it's thawed out completely.

Comment: The fat in milk and cream is not "mixed in" in a way a mixer can replicate. If you mix cream in a food processor or blender, first you'll have whipped cream, and later you'll have butter.